# How to make HYPERLINK formula fields that nominate Visualforce pages stay in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-ready

This HYPERLINK formula field on a custom object opens a Visualforce page in Classic:

```
HYPERLINK('/apex/DocumentRichTextEdit?id=' + Id + '&retURL=' + Claim__c, 'Edit', '_self')
```

I would like it to open that same Visualforce page in Lightning Experience embedded in the overall Lightning Experience page with a `$User.UIThemeDisplayed` of `Theme4d` so my conditional Lightning Experience styling applies. But the page is displayed as a Classic styled page with no header or footer which is quite a jarring end-user experience: the user is taken out of and back into Lightning Experience.

Is there a way to stay in Lightning Experience for this case (to somehow have `sforce.one.navigateToURL` execute)?